# Find out what javascript function was called on element with firebug or other?

Tags: javascript, firebug, nextgen-gallery

I have NextGEN javascript image gallery that loads an image. I need to find out what function loads the image to insert a tracking code.

What has not worked:

1. Searching the entire code for name of the element.
2. Firebug command-line doesn't execute any commands or work properly, such as console.trace etc.

I'm looking for the 'showImage' or equivalent function. There are so many possibilities that I would rather just be able to pinpoint in firebug, by clicking on the image - that way I know for sure which function, and am not guessing.

Is there not a way to see Javascript code by element?

Comment: I don't know a way to find references to an element via any developer tools, but depending on the situation you might be able to search for the URL it loads it from, which you can find from firebug (or developer tools)

Comment: I found out Chrome developer tools shows Event Listeners. Firebug has no equivalent feature. It looks like you might be able to run some commands or read logs through Firebug, but seems extra work.

Comment: There is a Firebug extension Eventbug for doing the same thing, and HTML panel breakpoints can often help too.

Comment: eq: $('button').click.toString();